# Add a custom field to order on, DAO

Tags: go, dao, go-gorm

I use the [generator of GORM](https://gorm.io/gen/) to generate the model + queries from database.

I would like to order my results by a custom field on the query.

Example of the raw request :

```sql
SELECT *, (CASE
    WHEN b IS NOT NULL AND b = "c" THEN 1
    WHEN d IS NOT NULL AND d = 1 THEN 2
    // ...
    ElSE 1
    END
) AS HIDDEN order_case FROM table ORDER BY order_case WHERE a IS NOT NULL;
```

and the Go code

```golang
a, err := query.Table.Select(??).OrderBy(??).Where(query.Table.A.IsNotNull()).Find()
```

I'm not able to find the good way to do it, maybe a custom `field.Expr`

Comment: use `Raw` replace `Select` https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Raw-SQL

Comment: I can't with DAO generated code, Raw is not available, I tried with a custom select clause but "select is banned" (https://github.com/go-gorm/gen/issues/545)